# ipython: Notebook does not appear to be JSON

Tags: python, markdown, psql

I have recently started working with the ipython notebook. Have created several test scripts for the same. 
On opening one of the files (.ipynb) it gives me an error:
" Unreadable Notebook: /home/dev/Feedbacks_exploration.ipynb NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: u''...",) "

This file included fetching data from psql, plotting of a line graph, and a block of markdown.

Can anyone please help guide me hoe to open this file? It has some of the important functions that could be used.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Copy the contents of the notebook, paste them into http://jsonlint.com/, and see what is wrong with the JSON.

Comment: The issue is, i cant open the notebook. Also, if i try to open it using text editor, all i get is a blank file. How should i go about it?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified when I said copy the contents that I meant using a plain text editor. If it shows a blank file then maybe it's a blank file and the data was lost somehow. What happens if you `ls -l`, `wc`, or `head` the file?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that it's not a blank file? What size is it? Do you know how to use a terminal and if so what happens when you run any of the above commands?

Comment: If i paste it on the text editor, it gives me a blank file only. I guess the has gone blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced similar problem when I'm using IPython notebook (Jupyter) for H2O. I installed Anaconda Ver 3.X and when i did with Anaconda 2.7.9 it worked without the JSON error. It's because IPython (Jupyter) doesn't yet support for Version 3.X of Anaconda (Python)

Answer (score 8):

The problem for me was that I had an unresolved merge conflict in my ipython notebook. So I opened the file and deleted one version (`HEAD>>>>>` and what came after it up until `=======` and then the line containing `<<<<<<`). In short, resolve the merge conflict and you'll be good.

Comment: My ipynb is too long and contains images. I cannot edit it by hand, it makes the editor go laggy. Is there an automated tool that would resolve the conflict automatically and give me one or both versions ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once when I tried to use `nbformat` to read in several notebooks that I was currently running (including the one from which I ran the `nbformat` commands). The error went away the next time I tried loading the notebooks (I might have saved in between) and hasn't occurred again since.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and neen able to solve it in the following way.

- First rename your Jupiter notebook from ipynb to HTML and then
- Convert it again in ipynb using the procedure described in the following post:
  [IPython notebook: Convert an HTML notebook to ipynb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972614/ipython-notebook-convert-an-html-notebook-to-ipynb)

It is a bit of quirky solution but it works.