# convert jupyter notebook saved as .HTML file back into .IPYNB

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

Can I convert a Jupyter Notebook saved as `.HTML` file back into `.IPYNB` file? The  executable original notebooks were lost. The `nbconvert` docs don't have anything useful for this case. Currently I have to copy-paste bunch of cells into a new notebook, but this is very tedious and output cells will be lost this way.

---

[EDIT]

I found an interactive way to do this using BeautifulSoup:

[IPython notebook: Convert an HTML notebook to ipynb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972614/ipython-notebook-convert-an-html-notebook-to-ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REMOVED ANSWER ATTEMPT because pandoc only results in a markdown representation of the notebook input and output cells as a single notebook cell.

Best I found so far that gets at the OP's question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47138762/8508004). I've added a notebook demonstrating it. You can work through it in your browser in temporary sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/back_to_ipynb) and served via the MyBInder service. Go there and click on `launch binder` to get started. This way everything there is already set to try it all out without needing to touch your own machine or computational environments.
**Bear in mind it isn't perfect as notebook `.ipynb` to HTML is meant to be one-way. BEST TO ALWAYS KEEP YOUR ORIGINAL `.ipynb` files**; clear out output if absolutely necessary to save space.