# How to re-import a jupyter html file?

Tags: python, jupyter

A coworker sent a jupyter notebook converted into html format. I want to edit it, how can I open the html in my jupyter environment?

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a dublicate of [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972614/ipython-notebook-convert-an-html-notebook-to-ipynb), you might also ask your college to send you the original file, or open the html in your browser and copy the code into a new notebook

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open it directly.  It needs to be converted back into an executable .ipynb Jupyter file.

Take a look at this code example to do the conversion:

[File-conversion of HTML-published Jupyter Notebook to Executable Jupyter.ipynb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194442/file-conversion-of-html-published-jupyter-notebook-to-executable-jupyter-ipynb-f?noredirect=1&lq=1)